# PowerShell WinEvent FilterHashtable wildcard

Tags: windows, powershell, event-viewer

This is my first time working in `PowerShell`. I'm trying to filter events based on Date only.

According to the documentation, `Logname` and `Providername` accept wildcard characters.

How can I wildcard the `Logname` ? I have tried *, ** but it does seem to work.

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname=*; StartTime=$startTime; EndTime=$endTime}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can.  Here's how I get around it.  You can't even do this in event viewer, events from all logs within a certain time.  There's an old windows api limit to the number of lognames.  Foreach-object -parallel in powershell 7 is faster.

```
Get-WinEvent -ListLog * -EA silentlycontinue | 
foreach-object { get-winevent -filterhashtable @{logname=$_.logname; 
  starttime='1:55 pm'; endtime='1:58 pm'} -ea 0 }
```

```
# powershell 7
get-winevent -LogName *

Get-WinEvent: Log count (458) is exceeded Windows Event Log API limit (256). 
Adjust filter to return less log names.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass wildcard to `Logname` but it should contain some non-wildcard chars too:

```
Get-WinEvent -EA silentlycontinue -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-App*";}
```